# Interface that all properties are strings and one property is number

Tags: typescript, interface

I want to define an interface like below.

```js
interface Foo {
   id: number,
   [x:string]: string
}
```

It means id is a numeric type and all other properties are strings. But I am getting and error. The error is:-

```
Property 'id' of type 'number' is not assignable to string index type 'string'.ts(2411)
```

How to solve this issue? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can't do this in TS with a concrete type; you can make a generic type like `type Foo<K extends PropertyKey> = {id: number} & Record<Exclude<K, "id">, string>` instead, which might meet your needs but I'd need to see use cases.  I'm inclined to close this as a duplicate of the linked question unless you can distinguish it in some meaningful way

Comment: This interface doesn't say "and all other properties are strings." This says that Foo can be subscripted by *any* string and return a string. Is that what you meant? (i.e. Record) Or did you mean "there is a set of other properties that return strings" or did you mean "there are no properties other than `id` that do not return strings?" jcalz's is "this can be subscripted by any string except `id` and will return a string, and `id` will return a number." But a type like `class C { id: number; name: string }` would not conform to that.

Comment: It would likely be helpful to show what types you expect to conform and which should not, and what algorithm you plan to use this interface for (why does a caller care?).

Comment: @jcalz Thank you to marking this as a duplicate! I have an answer in the question that you commented.

Comment: [This](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBAYg9nAPAFQHxQLxQN5QJYAmAXFAHYCuAtgEYQBOUAvlAGQ5QDaACvqVANYQQcAGZRkAXRI8IAD2ARSBAM5QARITVQA-FHKl+pOAHc+JZcDp5SAcyYBuALAAoFy5H6AxsDxw+AQ2V4JGQoOQUlVWCUVFQAChEEEmQAShwXKCg6CGByOj5EuCdnRjdnTz8LKFUsQOC43H8SNS1GFPsoAHpOsLo6ODoAQnwCfFVKPGVlaxsXCtIq4EwoOoQGkebW9q6e+n6hkbGyOCWKGno5yqXyZdW4dcISAEYmbe6oOH5-EEuFpYA3W5BNa4R5QJ4AGhWJAATK8Ou89gNhv4jkYlhYrLZflVjED6qDiOCoU11FsET1Pt8cUtZPiQRtidCyVDqJsoZ5NvCdh8vj9ylcoCB6fdCc8SeyoGyWVBOVARP4ADbKaBtCm9fbDTxok7VSwzFxAA) might work for you.  Good luck!